# Не отрисовывает QWidget

Tags: qt

Вот весь код, не могу понять почему не отрисовывает хотя в QWidget прописан.

mymainwindows.h

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#define MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#include <QMainWindow>

//namespace Ui { // возможно убери эту херню
class MyMainWindow;
//}
class MyMainWindows:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit
     MyMainWindows(QWidget *parent =0);
};

#endif // MYMAINWINDOWS_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include "mymainwindows.h"

using namespace std;

//int main()
//{
//    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
//    return 0;
//}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindows w;

    w.setWindowTitle("PCAN-view_litle");
    w.resize(230, 200); // перересуй от размера экрана

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mymainwindows.cpp

```
#include "mymainwindows.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>


MyMainWindows::MyMainWindows (QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    QLabel* L_ID = new QLabel("ID:(hex)");
    QLabel* L_Length = new QLabel("Length");
    QLabel* L_Data_h = new QLabel("Data:(hex) ");
    QLabel* L_CTime = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
    QLabel* L_ms = new QLabel("ms");
    QLabel* L_Paused = new QLabel("Paused");
    QLabel* L_CAN_ID = new QLabel("CAN-ID");
//    QLabel* L_CTime = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
    QLabel* L_Type = new QLabel("Type");
    QLabel* L_Data = new QLabel("Data ");
    QLabel* L_Count = new QLabel("Count");

    QLineEdit* LE_ID = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Length = new QLineEdit();
    // создать вектор указателей QPushButton, при создании кнопок запихивать их в вектор, а далее работать с элементами вектора.
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_0 = new QLineEdit(); // проверить через вектор
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_1 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_2 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_3 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_4 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_5 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_6 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_7 = new QLineEdit();

    QLineEdit* LE_CTime = new QLineEdit();
    QCheckBox* CH_Paused = new QCheckBox();

    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_ID = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_ID->addWidget(L_ID);
    phb_L_ID->addWidget(LE_ID);
    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Length = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Length->addWidget(L_Length);
    phb_L_Length->addWidget(LE_Length);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Data_i = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_0);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_1);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_2);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_3);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_4);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_5);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_6);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_7);
    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Data  = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Data->addWidget(L_Data_h);
    phb_L_Data->addLayout(phb_L_Data_i);
    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime  = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_CTime->addWidget(L_CTime);
    phb_L_CTime->addWidget(LE_CTime);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Paused = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Paused->addWidget(CH_Paused);
    phb_L_Paused->addWidget(L_Paused);
    QGridLayout* pgr_L = new QGridLayout();
    pgr_L->setMargin(5);
    pgr_L->setSpacing(15);

    QVBoxLayout * phb_Lin_Werh = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_ID);
    phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_Length);

    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_Lin_Werh,0,0);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Data,0,1);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_CTime,1,0);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Paused,1,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в конце mymainwindows.cpp

надо ввести команду     setLayout(pgr_L);

```
....
pgr_L->addLayout(phb_Lin_Werh,0,0);
pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Data,0,1);
pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_CTime,1,0);
pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Paused,1,1);

setLayout(pgr_L); //добавляем эту команду
```